# How to correctly manage maps initial state in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm new to JS/React-native and I'm a bit confused as to how I can correctly manage a maps initial state.

I've got the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 53.2274476;
const LONGITUDE = -0.5474525;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;


function myMapsComponent({navigation}) {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      location: null,
      errorMessage: null,
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
    }
  }


  return (
      <MapView style={{flex: 1}} Initialregion={this.state.region}/>
  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default myMapsComponent;
```

This code produces the error `expected ";" (16:21)` Which is the line where the constructor starts. I'm guessing that the problem is actually that I can't use a constructor unless it's within a class rather than a function?

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Why are you using a constructor inside a functional component? Check [React Fundamentals](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react#your-first-component) to see differences between function and class components.

Comment: @JuanMarco I do actually say in the question that "I'm guessing that the problem is actually that I can't use a constructor unless it's within a class rather than a function". I was looking more for guidance on how I can adapt my code to a class/functional component like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you can't use a constructor in a function component.

What you can do is choose the one or the other.
A class component would look like this:

```
class MyMapsComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      ...
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <MapView style={{flex: 1}} Initialregion={this.state.region}/>
    );
  }
}
```

And a function component like this:

```
function myMapsComponent({navigation}) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({longitude: LONGITUDE, ...});
  ...


  return (
      <MapView style={{flex: 1}} Initialregion={region}/>
  );

}
```

You can learn about components (function or class) [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), and about `useState` and other hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. Quick question, would my navigation still work with the class component? I notice it isn't mentioned anywhere within the code snippet?

Comment: It is passed in as props in the constructor, which lets you write `this.props.navigation` wherever you need it.